# Does the method of reruning GARCH models every day (to update parameter values and improve out-of-sample forecasting performance) have a name?

Tags: forecasting, terminology, garch, volatility-forecasting, moving-window

It is my understanding that normally GARCH models make forecasts for say T-K days ahead.  Instead of doing that I would like to use the data for days 1, 2, ...,k in my dataset to fit a GARCH model to make a 1-day ahead forecast for day k+1. Then I would like to use days 1, 2, ..., k+1 to fit a new GARCH model and to make a 1-day ahead forecast for day k+2.  I would like to keep repeating this process and end up doing it a total of T - k times, with the last time consisting of me using the days 1, 2, ..., T-1 to fit GARCH model to make a 1-day ahead forecast for day T. Does this approach have a name in the literature? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is simply known as *expanding-window estimation*. This can be contrasted to *rolling-window estimation* (also *moving-window estimation*) where you keep the window size fixed by discarding initial observations when you add new ones. (We have the tag [moving-window](/questions/tagged/moving-window) for that.)

This is not specific to GARCH models but can be used with any time series model.

The forecasts obtained using the rolling-window method may be called *rolling forecasts*. (I suspect forecasts from expanding-window estimation might be called *rolling forecasts*, too.)

Comment: Thank you, Richard!  This is exactly what I was looking for.  I have heard of the "rolling-window", but I knew that it couldn't be applied to the case where one end point of the window doesn't move. I will now be able to use this keyword to find more studies that are relevant for my project.  Thank you!

Comment: @BillB, you are welcome!